# Error while installing socket.io on an Ubuntu VM on a Windows host

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io, npm, virtualbox

I had the following error while installing socket.io using the command `npm install socket.io`:

`npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '<path_to_project>/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/test/autobahn-server.js'`

I am using Windows and developing in an Ubuntu VM using Virtual Box.
`<path_to_project>` is a shared folder (owned by the Windows host).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm is trying to create symbolic links while installing the package, and it is impossible to do so on a Windows shared folder, hence the error.

To workaround that, tell npm to not create any symlinks with `--no-bin-links`.

For example, `npm install --no-bin-links` when installing with a package.json file.

Reference: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html